# owl:allValuesFrom and rdfs:range difference

Tags: semantics, owl, rdfs

I'm working on semantic webs and I'm wondering: is there any difference in a semanitc of writing a restriction like:

```
:Person
  a owl:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf
    [ a owl:Restriction ;
      owl:onProperty :hasParent ;
      owl:allValuesFrom :Person
   ] .
```

and writing a range restriction like:

```
:hasParent rdfs:range :Person.
```

It seems to me that it means the same: a parent has to have a type of Person. Isn't there any difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first snippet means that a `:Person` who has a parent necessarily have a `:Person`-parent. However, a `:Dog` may have a parent who is not a `:Person`, for instance. The second snippet says that anything who has a parent necessarily has a `:Person`-parent, regardless of what this thing is.

Edit after krajol's comment:

The `allValuesFrom` restriction of the first snippet is not equivalent to:

```
:hasParent  rdfs:domain  :Person;
            rdfs:range   :Person .
```

In the case of the `allValuesFrom` restriction, it is still possible that there are parents that are not persons. In the case of the `rdfs:domain`/`rdfs:range` combination, it is not possible. With `allValuesFrom` restrictions, it's possible to say that persons have person-parents and that dogs have dog-parents, etc. With domain/range, you cannot.

Comment: Well, that's right. But if a statement like:
    :hasParent rdfs:domain :Person.
was added, would it be the same then?

Comment: @krajol, setting the domain to `:Person` means that everyone that has a parent is a Person. If you combine that with the OWL restriction above, then yes, the logical consequence is that everything that has a parent is a Person, and everything that _is_ a parent is a Person.

The difference between domain/range on the one hand and class restrictions on the other is that domain/range are always global, while class restrictions are only valid for the class you define them on.

Answer (score 1):

There's another difference worth noting.  When there are more than one rdfs:range (or rdfs:domain) triple on a class, the range or domain is the *conjunction* (intersection) of the stated ranges/domains.  See [the RDFS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_range), though the wording is ambiguous, and [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511163112/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/25408/multiple-property-domain-and-range-conjunction-vs-intersection#25410).

If inferencing is performed on the ontology, you'll find that rdfs:range/domain triples are inferred for all of the superclasses of the stated range/domain class(es).  While semantically correct, this may be confusing or difficult to work with.  This won't happen with *allValuesFrom*.

Comment: What do you mean by "this won't happen with allValuesFrom"? If you have `:Person rdfs:subClassOf [ a owl:Restriction; owl:onProperty :hasParent; owl:allValuesFrom :Person ]` and `:Person rdfs:subClassOf :Agent`, then you can infer that `:Person rdfs:subClassOf [ a owl:Restriction; owl:onProperty :hasParent; owl:allValuesFrom :Agent ]`.

Answer (score 1):

(Adding an answer to an already answered question since I found the essence of the accepted answer lacking.)

```
[ a owl:Restriction ;
    owl:onProperty :hasParent ;
    owl:allValuesFrom :Person
]
```

can be read as "the class of all things for which any value for the `hasParent` predicate (potentially none) is of the type `Person`".

By saying that `Person` is a subclass of this class, we say that it is a more specialised version of this class. So, `Person` still can only have other `Person`s as value for `hasParent`.

This differs from `rdfs:range` because we make no statement about the valid domain/range for `hasParent` itself. To recycle [Antoine's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11842249/1260887), we can still say:

```
:dog1 a :Dog.
:dog2 a :Dog.
:dog1 :hasParent :dog2.
```

Comment: "the class of all things that have a Person as value for the hasParent predicate" could be misleading. This class includes, for instance, things that do not have any value for the `hasParent` property. It'd be better to say "the class of all things of which all parents are persons."

Comment: Good remark - I've updated the description to clarify that it also applies when the `hasParent` doesn't occur.